# Location update takes a long time after reboot, using FusedLocationProviderClient

Tags: android, kotlin, fusedlocationproviderclient

I'm using the `FusedLocationProviderClient` to access the `lastLocation` of the user. If it's null, I'm waiting for `requestLocationUpdates` to return.

I've tested this on my Pixel 3a by rebooting the device, which clears the last location, however it takes >2 mins to return a location.

Here's my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
    private fun onLocationPermissionGranted() {
        val fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(
            requireContext()
        )

        fusedLocationProviderClient.flushLocations()

        Log.i("Jamie", "Attempting to access last location")

        val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
        locationRequest.interval = 5000
        locationRequest.numUpdates = 1

        val callback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
                Log.i("Jamie", "Calling location permission granted again")
                onLocationPermissionGranted()
            }
        }

        fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                Log.i("Jamie", "FusedLocation onsuccess called")
                if (location == null) {
                    Log.i("Jamie", "location null")
                }

                location?.let {
                    fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(callback)
                    Log.i("Jamie", "Location received")
                    this.map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                    viewModel.currentLocation = location
                    updateCamera(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                }
            }

        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, callback, Looper.getMainLooper())
    }
```

```
2020-08-31 14:04:33.834 3780-3780/com.redacted I/Jamie: Attempting to access last location
2020-08-31 14:04:34.547 3780-3780/com.redacted I/Jamie: FusedLocation onsuccess called
2020-08-31 14:04:34.547 3780-3780/com.redacted I/Jamie: location null
2020-08-31 14:06:50.404 3780-3780/com.redacted I/Jamie: Calling location permission granted again
2020-08-31 14:06:50.404 3780-3780/com.redacted I/Jamie: Attempting to access last location
2020-08-31 14:06:50.517 3780-3780/com.redacted I/Jamie: FusedLocation onsuccess called
2020-08-31 14:06:50.517 3780-3780/com.redacted I/Jamie: Location received
```

Comment: _"it takes >2 mins to return a location."_ It might be normal if for example the only provider available is the GPS and you are perhaps indoors where it's more difficult to get a fix on the signals. _"What am I doing wrong?"_ Maybe nothing. You do get a location in the end, so the code works. Try inserting a functional SIM card into the device if there's none yet. The rough location based on the cell towers should help with the GPS fix. (But you'll then get cell tower based locations only if you keep using `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`, I believe.)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Rough location is fine for this use case, however my test device has no SIM. I would expect it to use the Wifi/internet connection location before falling back to GPS? Is there not a way to force this that you know of? (I expect this app to be used in places with poor cell tower network coverage).

Comment: Wi-Fi base station based locations are not available everywhere as there might not be any base stations whose location is known.

Comment: @JamieNewman How long does Google Maps take to find your location after reboot?

Comment: @GavinWright It varies. Sometimes instant. Sometimes 2 minutes. Sometimes I've kept the screen open for 10 mins+ and my callback isn't called.

Comment: @JamieNewman No, I mean if you open the Google Maps app. How long does that app take to get a GPS lock after reboot?

Comment: @GavinWright Seconds (less than 10, and in most cases instant). I'm not sure if that app is implementing location caching between reboots or not, but it seems to work fine.

Comment: I really dislike the way `getLastLocation()` works. Try this project which checks for the location every few seconds and see if that speeds things up: https://github.com/gavingt/basic_location_improved